# Memory Leak in kafka

Tags: memory-leaks, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, metrics

We have built a data ingestion pipeline using Kafka. We have a consumer that reads from a kafka topic and writes to a database continuously. These consumer pods is experiencing issues with OOM events. We run kafka on top of k8s.

We are now seeing that the consumer pods are being restarted every 4-5 days due to OOM error. We are using Kafka 2.2 version of the kafka java libs.

compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.12', version: '2.2.0'
        compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '2.2.0'

Here are the stats from the jvm inside the pod:

```
  15:          6075         145800  org.apache.kafka.common.requests.ApiVersionsResponse$ApiVersion
  16:          4030         128960  org.apache.kafka.common.MetricName
  17:          4030         128960  org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.KafkaMetric
  22:          1672          80256  org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.stats.SampledStat$Sample
  24:          1174          75136  org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Sensor
  27:          1261          40352  org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.stats.Meter
  29:          1291          30984  org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.stats.Total
  30:          1261          30264  org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.stats.Rate
  32:           849          27168  org.apache.kafka.common.MetricNameTemplate
  35:           975          23400  org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.BoundField



/ # jcmd {app}.jar GC.class_histogram | head

 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:          1828        5264368  [B
   2:         33683        2949528  [C
   3:          7422         832008  java.lang.Class
   4:         33674         808176  java.lang.String
   5:         10990         764272  [Ljava.lang.Object;
   6:         23875         764000  java.util.HashMap$Node
```

When I started analyzing the heap dumps, I thought the issue is with the KafkaAdminClient threads which are open in 100's on the jvms and never closed. I closed them properly and tried to look the heap after that. I still see that the issue persists.

Can I know what operation in kafka produces the above mentioned classes? Is it the consumer.poll() or the background health check or something else.

Any pointer in the right direction would be great help. I am stuck with this for more than a week now. I tried many different Heap dump analyzers. All of them point to JMX and NIO classes.

Here is one leak suspect report from Eclipse MAT:

`One instance of "com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer" loaded by "<system class loader>" occupies 61,571,856 (36.76%) bytes. The instance is referenced by org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection @ 0xf0647668 , loaded by "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0xf09a3bd8". The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.util.HashMap$Node[]" loaded by "<system class loader>".`

and

````
sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper```
````